# How to deal to convert quantative data into categorical data using pandas

Tags: pandas

I am working on a data set which consists of columns with numerical/int data. It consists of mainly -1s,0s and then spartially values among 10s and 1000s.I want to replace the coulmn content with labels...

```
pd.qcut(df['TS1'].rank(method='first'),3,labels=["low","mid","high"],duplicates='drop')
```

the command only converts one column, I dont know  how to categorize the whole dataset.

Comment: Do it in a loop on all columns?

Comment: ok got it...also can i use boxplot on this?

Comment: `df.boxplot(by='IDLink',column=['TS1'],grid=True)` using this results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I create a dataframe with data similar to your dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)) * 1000
df.iloc[0:3, 2] = 0
df.iloc[[1, 3], :] = -1
print(df)
```

output:

```
        0           1         2
0  679.473489  844.456345    0.0000
1   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.0000
2  125.684455  696.829219    0.0000
3   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.0000
4   97.520572  869.919917  528.5606
```

Create a dataframe for the categories, then loop over columns to get the qcut for each column:

```
cat_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

for column in df.columns:
    cat_df[column] = pd.qcut(df.loc[:,column],3,labels=["low","mid","high"],duplicates='drop')

print(cat_df)
```

output:

```
  0     1     2
0  high  high   mid
1   low   low   low
2  high   mid   mid
3   low   low   low
4   mid  high  high
```

Then boxplot:

```
df.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

[image]